# MYSQL Insert ID from previous Insert

Tags: mysql

There are two tables that need to have new rows added.

```
table fish 
  fish_id
  name
  color

table tank
  tank_id
  fish_id
```

Say I want to insert a new fish and then assign it to a tank with it's newly created fish_id. Is there a way to do this in one query? Or would you have to insert the new fish, get the id, then do another insert?

Comment: There is no way to insert rows into more than one table in one statement, so you must do it the second way you said.

Answer (score 3):

You can use LAST_INSERT_ID function to do this in two consecutive queries.

```
INSERT INTO fish (fish_id,name,color)
VALUES(NULL,'fish','red');

INSERT INTO tank (tank_id, fish_id)
VALUES(100, LAST_INSERT_ID());
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this using trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER `after_insert_fish`  
    AFTER INSERT ON `fish` FOR EACH ROW  
    BEGIN  
        INSERT INTO tank (fish_id)  
        VALUES (NEW.fish_id);  
    END
```

Comment: I would not advise using triggers in mysql as they can be quite dangeroues (they do not cascade, errors in triggers yields not intuitive errors, etc.)